# Is this dependency injection example & explanation correct?

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection

I am learning dependency injection.  After reading many posts and using a book, the code below is based on what I've read and an example from the book.  This console program works.  Before continuing to learn more about DI and it's use in unit testing, I would like to confirm if I'm understanding it correctly, and if I'm coding it correctly.

Main

```
Sub Main()

  Dim myWriter As IMessageWriter                 'myWriter must be same type as ConsoleMessageWriter, next line.  That is INTERFACE type IMessageWriter
  myWriter = New ConsoleMessageWriter()          'myWriter INSTANCE is required to construct MyConsoleWriter INSTANCE below

  Dim myConsoleWriter As ConsoleWriter           'myConsoleWriter must be same type as ConsoleWriter, next line. That is CLASS type ConsoleWriter
  myConsoleWriter = New ConsoleWriter(myWriter)  'myConsoleWriter INSTANCE contructed w/ myWriter INSTANCE. myConsoleWriter exposes ConsoleWrite

  myConsoleWriter.ConsoleWrite("Hello DI world.", True) 'INSTANCE myConsoleWriter's ConsoleWrite method uses INSTANCE MyWriter's Write method
End Sub
```

ConsoleWriter

```
Public Class ConsoleWriter

  Private ReadOnly writer As IMessageWriter

  Public Sub New(writer As IMessageWriter)
    If writer Is Nothing Then
      Throw New ArgumentNullException("writer")
    End If
    Me.writer = writer
  End Sub    

  Public Sub ConsoleWrite(message As String, pause As Boolean)
    Me.writer.Write(message, pause)
  End Sub
End Class
```

ConsoleMessageWriter

```
Public Class ConsoleMessageWriter
  Implements IMessageWriter

  Public Sub Write(message As String, pause As Boolean) Implements IMessageWriter.Write

    If pause Then
      Console.WriteLine(message)
      Console.WriteLine("<press any key to continue>")
      Console.ReadKey()
    Else
      Console.WriteLine(message)
    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

IMessageWriter

```
Public Interface IMessageWriter
  Sub Write(message As String, pause As Boolean)
End Interface
```

I added comments in the code above to remind me why each step is taken, and the graphic below is a picture I created to try to understand this methodology.
[image]

My questions are simple.  Is there anything wrong with the code?  The comments in the code?  The graphic?  Regarding the code, I understand several lines could be combined, but I broke them out to enhance my basic understanding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code correctly demonstrates the concept of dependency injection and your diagram correctly demonstrates how the `myConsoleWriter.ConsoleWrite` call is executed.  The only thing I would change is your comment that says `myWriter must be same type as ConsoleMessageWriter, next line.  That is INTERFACE type IMessageWriter`  That's not really accurate.  `myWriter` doesn't have to be of type `ConsoleMessageWriter`, it just has to be a type that implements `IMessageWriter`.  So if you had a `Public Class OtherConsoleMessageWriter Implements IMessageWriter`, then `myWriter` could of type `OtherConsoleMessageWriter` too.

That being said, make sure that you understand that the way that your `Main` method is written is just to demonstrate that concept of injecting a dependency into `ConsoleWriter`, and that in an actual program, you don't want to do `myWriter = New ConsoleMessageWriter()`.  Since you're learning dependency injection, I assume that you haven't gotten to the topic of DI containers yet.  The gist of it is that you never want to explicity create your dependencies because then you're hard-coding your dependencies to be a specific type (`ConsoleMessageWriter` in your case).  DI containers will let you configure the container so that you can tell it which concrete type to return for each interface, and then you let the DI container create all of your dependencies, but you'll get to that as your read more.

Comment: Thx!  I'm changing my 1st comment to `myWriter must implement the same interface as ConsoleMessageWriter, next line.  That is INTERFACE type IMessageWriter`; is that more accurate?  And yes, I realize I will need to use DI containers & am working up to that.  Would it be correct to see DI containers in a similar way as using what is often named a RelayCommand Class implementing ICommand instead of individual Classes implementing ICommand?

Comment: I would change the comment to `myWriter must implement interface IMessageWriter` and not say anything in the comment about `ConsoleMessageWriter`.  Since everything in dependency injection is only concerned with interfaces, nothing in `ConsoleWriter` should know that the class `ConsoleMessageWriter` exists.  `ConsoleWriter` only cares that it is being given a dependency that implements `IMessageWriter`.

Comment: DI containers are different from `RelayCommand`, and they satisfy two unrelated purposes.  DI containers work like this: somewhere at the beginning of your program, in the composition root, you wire up all of your classes and dependencies.  So when you create your `ConsoleWriter` object, you need to pass in an object that implements `IMessageWriter`.  In your example you create a `new ConsoleMessageWriter`.  With a DI container, you tell your container to create an object that implements `IMessageWriter` and pass that in as your dependency.  That way `ConsoleMessageWriter` isn't hard-coded.